# Why this expression returns 10 when I expect it to return 15?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the Python console, this code should return 15, but it returns 10.
What is wrong?

```
print(sum(range(5)))
```

Comment: Run `range(5)` to see what that sub expression gives you

Comment: `range(n)` starts with `0` to `n-1`. For more information, refer [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `range`s are exclusive, they don't include the last (`stop`) element you've specified, from [the documentation on range objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

> For a positive step, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` *and `r[i] < stop`*

omitting the `step` defaults to a value of `1`.

You're essentially summing this:

```
list(range(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

which, obviously, sums to `10`.

Comment: My bad, I mixed it up with print(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).

Answer (score 0):

In python,

`range(5)` is equivalent to `[0,5)`